# Finding general formula for constrained polynomial

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

I have a degree 3 polynomial such that:

$p(a) = 1; p(b) = 0; p'(a) = 0; p'(b) = 0$.

I am trying to find the general formula for such polynomials. I know that if a,b are given I can just solve a linear system of equations in 4 variables and 4 unknowns. However doing the algebra for that and coming to a clean result is turning tedious.

I can also just note that the derivative is quadratic and so we know that the derivative is just $A(x-a)(x-b)$ for some constant $A$ and we can thus integrate and use the boundary conditions to solve for the A and the constant of integration. That's also proving to be a chore of arithmetic.

I am wondering if there is something clever I can leverage to just express what the polynomial should be without having to outright solve a system of 4 unknowns.

Comment: The problem is very simple if you take into account the fact that $p(b)=p'(b)=0$ means that $b$ is a double root

Comment: Ok, so I know that the polynomial is of the form $(x-b)^2(x-\alpha)$ but how do i find $\alpha$?

Comment: Take care : the polynomial is of the form $A (x−b)^2(x−α)$